# Windows Vista Home memory usage problem

Tags: windows, memory, windows-vista

I have a Windows Vista Home laptop from a client that is running on 1GB ram. The laptop is used for super basic things, word, internet, outlook, etc.

What makes zero sense is that the RAM is being completely consumed, causing the PC to hang sometimes when it can't take it anymore. However, in task manager, the processes appear to only be consuming maybe 100MB (Private Working Set).

The client literally has a simple setup, and is running kaspersky, though that does not seem to be indicating it is the cause of the excessive memory usage.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to resolve the memory issue or how to track down what is actually happening and fix it?

G

Comment: Check your pagefile settings and report back here with how large it is (ensure that it is at least 1.5 GB).  You may also want to disable some unneeded Windows services to free up more RAM.

Comment: Pagefile was sitting at 1314MB. I also downloaded Process Explorer to view more details on what is being consumed. SVCHOST is consuming about 200MB and Search Indexer is consuming about 125MB.

Answer (score 0):

The RAM being completely consumed is normal and has nothing to do with the problem. Free RAM would just make things worse, as that would mean the system isn't using every resource at its disposal to cope with its load.

A PC hanging usually has very little to do with memory usage. When the system hangs, what exactly happens? Does it freeze? Do you get massive disk I/O?

You really haven't described the problem, just described what you think the cause is. It's like "Doctor, I have a tumor, what should I do?" You need to let the doctor diagnose that you have a tumor. First, because you may not have a tumor. And second, the process of the doctor convincing himself that you have a tumor will give him the information he needs to know what to do about it.